# I am trying to implement kernel least mean square but I am getting this error -> Inner matrix dimensions must agree

Tags: matlab, signals, signal-processing, least-squares

I have written the code below, for kernel least mean square. All other code is correct in my opinion, I am only facing issue with matrix dimensions. For as far as i understood there is a problem in the klms loop where i have applied lms to kernel adaptive filtering hence klms. calculated its mean square error.

```
Sensors = 10; %number of recievers
samples = 1000; %number of set of signals
p = 10; %number of signals
angles = [10 20 40 60 100 120 140 80 90 110]*(pi/180);
X = zeros(Sensors,samples);
for k=1:p-1 %for loop
    Array_factor = exp(j*pi*cos(angles(1,k))*(0:Sensors-1 )); %array factor
    br =ones(1,samples); %creating real values between 1-1000
    temp = rand(1,samples); %generate random numbers b/w 1 and 1000
    br(find(temp<.5))=-1; %find real numbers
    bi =ones(1,samples); %creating imaginary values between 1-1000
    temp = rand(1,samples); %generate complex random numbers b/w 1 and 1000
    bi(find(temp<.5))=-1; %find imaginary numbers
    b = br+j*bi; #real + imaginary
    X = X +Array_factor'*b; %complete Input signal combined with array factor
end
%Desired Signal
A = exp(j*pi*cos(angles(1,p))*(0:Sensors-1)); %setting referernce for desired signal
dr =ones(1,samples); %creating real values between 1-1000
temp = rand(1,samples); %generate random numbers b/w 1 and 1000
dr(find(temp<.5))=-1; %find real numbers
di =ones(1,samples); %creating imaginary values between 1-1000
temp = rand(1,samples); %generate complex random numbers b/w 1 and 1000
di(find(temp<.5))=-1; %find imaginary numbers
d = dr+j*di; %desired real + desired imaginary
X = X +A'*d; %complete Input signal combined with array factor
X = awgn(X,13); % Input signal + anti-white gaussian noise signal and 13=> signal to noise ratio
Rxx = zeros(Sensors,Sensors); 
mu = 0.002; %StepSize
sse=0; %sum of square error
w=zeros(1,Sensors); %weights

for n=1:samples %for loop
    Rxx = Rxx + X(:,n)*X(:,n)'; %auto correlation
end
%kernel function
sigma = 0.1; %Adjust this parameter based on problem
kernel_function = @(x,y)exp(-norm(x-y)^2/(2*sigma^2));
%Compute kernel matrix for all input data pairs
k = zeros(samples, samples); %defining k 
for i = 1:samples
    for j=1:samples
        k(i,j) = kernel_function(X(:,i),X(:,j));
    end
end
%Implementing Kernel Least Mean Square (KLMS)
for n = 1:samples
    %y(1,n) = w*X(:,n); %estimated output signal
    y(1,n) = w*k(:,n)'; %estimated output signal
    e(n) = d(n) - y(1,n); %error
    w1 = w + mu*e(n)*k(:,n); %weights optimization (error)
    w = w1;
    se(n) = (abs(e(n)))^2; %square of errors
    sse = sse + se(n); %sum of square errors
    LMSE(n) = 20*log10((sse/n)); %logarithmic least mean square 
end
```

**Output = Inner matrix dimensions must agree**

Comment: Are you perhaps looking for elementwise multiplication (`.*`) instead of matrix multiplication (`*`)? It would be easier to help if you would provide _where_ the error is

Comment: Yes the error exists in the loop where I mentioned KLMS algorithm.
Most probably in the line **w1 = w + mu*e(n)*k( : , n)**

Comment: @AnderBiguri I tried the element wise operator but it doesn't work. 
The error either points the line **y(1,n) = w*k(:,n)** or it points at **w1 = w + mu*e(n)*k(: , n)**

Comment: There is no "most probably" the error message tells you *exactly* where

Comment: well, `y(1,n)` is of size 1x1, so `w*k(:,n)'` needs to be of size 1x1. Is it?

Comment: That could be it. But Still no success. :(
What i understood is **k** should be `k(1,n)'` as well?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254659/discussion-between-owais-ishtiaq-and-ander-biguri).

Comment: `X` and `samples` are undefined in the snippet of code you posted, making it non reproducible. Could please define them?

Comment: @FerroLuca I edited the code above you can check it now

Comment: What I dont understand is, you have written this code accordingly to some source (book or paper or lecture etc.), which you are not providing here and expect now someone else to debug it for you? How should this work? Have you considered to debug it yourself? Use break points? Do some calculation with a pen and paper and compare it?

Comment: at line `y(1,n) = w*k(:,n)'`, `w` is of size 1x10 and is multiplied to `k(:,n)` which is of size 1x1000. and you are trying to assign it to `y(1,n)` which is supposedly of  dimension 1x2.
Also for some reason `k` is a NaN matrix, which i doubt is correct